# mostrar produto/imóvel semelhantes com php e mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Estou desenvolvendo um recurso no meu site para mostrar os imóveis semelhantes pelo titulo e pelo valo9r, porém não deu muito certo minha ideia:

```
<?php
//Armazeno o resultado do titulo da consulta anterior da tabela imoveis em um variável
$titulo_semelhante = $results['titulo'];
//Armazeno o resultado do valor do imóvel da consulta anterior em um variável
$valor_semelhante = $results['venda'];

//Realizo uma nova consulta, onde o titulo na tabela vw_exibir contenha a palavra da variavel $titulo_semelhante e contenha um valor menor ou igual a variavel $valor_semelhante
                    $q2 = $db->query("SELECT * from vw_exibir WHERE titulo LIKE '%$titulo_semelhante%' AND venda <= '".$valor_semelhante."' ");
                        foreach($q2 as $row){
                            print_r($row);
                        }
                    ?>
```

Sempre me retorna esse erro:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Problem preparing query (SELECT * from vw_exibir WHERE titulo LIKE &#39;%Apartamento em Balneário Camboriú%&#39; AND venda ) Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a '&#39;%Apartamento em Balneário Camboriú%&#39; AND venda' na linha 1 in <b>/home/himoveis/www/includes/MysqliDb.php</b> on line <b>447</b><br />
```

Alguém pode dizer se estou desenvolvendo esse recurso de forma correta, e porque esta retornando esse erro?

OBS:

Utilizo a class - PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class
Quando faço a mesma consulta com valores estáticos no phpmyadmin tudo esta ok:

ex:`SELECT * from vw_exibir WHERE titulo LIKE '%Apertamento%' AND venda <= 1500000`

[image: imóveis semelhantes]

Comment: Tente usar `$db->prepare('Sua query');` e logo após use `$q2->execute()`

Comment: @RafaelAcioly, tentei e  tive esse retorno: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to undefined method MysqliDb::prepare() in <b>/home/****/www/exclusive/tpl/imovel.php</b> on line <b>225</b><br />

Comment: vá no seu local -> PHP -> PHP Extension ->  e selecione `php_pdo_mysql`

Comment: Já esta no servidor de hospedagem, pdo esta ativo.

Comment: Coloque o trecho do código que deu erro.

Comment: Diria que o seu problema é o encoding, provavelmente o seu encoding atual não permite certos caracteres. Está a extrair esse valor de um request de ajax?

Comment: Igor, pra fazer isso talvez será necessário mexer na sua modelagem. Pode colocar na pergunta a modelagem das suas tabelas que envolvem essa busca? Com base nessas informações irei elaborar uma resposta de utilidade pública.

Comment: `$db->query` 'e um metodo customizado? Pois as entidades html que apareceram me faz crer que voce criou um metodo proprio e usou htmlspecialchars ou htmlentities. Poderia dar mais detalhes do teu codido?